# Would hashcode() return the same hash for a connection?

Tags: java, hash, connection, hashcode, hikaricp

I am trying to ensure that I am grabbing the same connection from my HikariCP pool, and wanted to use hashcode() to test that they were the same. I am getting different hashes, does this mean I necessarily have different connections?

```java
    @Test
    public void testDBConnectionPool() throws Exception {
        logger.info("GlobalProps are the same. Instances-{}, {}, {}!", props.hashCode(), props1.hashCode(),
                GlobalProps.getInstance().hashCode());
        Connection con1 = DBConnectionPool.getInstance().getConnection();
        if (con1 != null) {
            PreparedStatement ps = con1.prepareStatement("SELECT count(*) FROM ALERT");

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                logger.info("Total Record Count: {} - Alert table", rs.getObject(1));
            }
        }

        con1.close();
        logger.info("Returned connection {} to the pool", con1.hashCode());

        con1 = DBConnectionPool.getInstance().getConnection();
        if (con1 != null) {
            PreparedStatement ps = con1.prepareStatement("SELECT count(*) FROM ALERT");

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                logger.info("Total Record Count: {} - Alert table", rs.getObject(1));
            }
        }
        con1.close();
        logger.info("Returned connection {} to the pool", con1.hashCode());
    }
```

Expected different hashes, but received the same hash.

Answer (score 0):

> does this mean I necessarily have different connections?

*Necessarily*?  No. In a general sense, it is possible for the same object to have different hash codes at different times.  This depends on its class's implementation of `hashCode()`.  But it is nevertheless *probable* that differing hash codes are a sign of different objects, and in most cases I would consider a class that affords the possibility of its instances' hash codes changing to be flawed.

Moreover, if the same object did report different hash codes at different times, then that almost surely conveys something about the state of that object, quite possibly with the implication that it should be considered logically a different object.

I don't quite know what to make of this, however:

> Expected different hashes, but received the same hash.

That seems to be contradicting your earlier comments, so I'll say no more than that having the same hash *does not*, in the general sense, indicate that two objects are the same, neither in an instance-identity sense nor in a value-identity sense.